# software to make guesses in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory

Does anybody knows a software which guesses relation and formulas in  Graph theory ? 
Actually I've heard there is but can't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking of [Graffiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graffiti_(program)) written by Siemion Fajtlowicz. For more information please read the
[research page of Ermelinda DeLaVina](http://cms.uhd.edu/faculty/delavinae/research/research.htm). I am sorry that I don't have any information about the actual software or if it is available to use.

Comment: thank you. Is that program available for computers ? or is there any site which share the open conjecture ? is it open source or close source ?